# The distance to the zero section of $TM$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Let $S_g$ be the corresponding Sasaki metric on $TM$. For every $p\in M$, $V_p\in T_pM$, is it true and obvious that $0_p$ is the closest point of  the zero section to $V_p$?

With some abuse of terminology a rephrase of the question would be:  Is the height of a right  triangle shorter than its hypotenuse?

Comment: You had $V_p \in TM$, which was surely meant to be $V_p \in T_pM$.  I changed it.

Comment: By Sasaki metric you mean the one using the Levi-Civita connection, correct?

Comment: Yes. Consider the function $f\colon V\mapsto |V|$. Note that $\nabla_Vf$ has vertical part $V/|V|$ if $V\ne0$ and its horizontal part vanishes. Make a conclusion.

Comment: @LSpice thank you for your edit!

Comment: @GabeK yes I mean the metric on TM arising from $\nabla$_ isomorphism between horisontal space and $T_p M$ from one hand and the vertical space and $T_p M$ from another hand.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin thank you for your comment. The gradient of length function is veryical then are you showing the geodesic paths? Is TM complet? I have another related question: let we have a Riemannian submersion and v, w liy on the same fiber. Does shortest path from p to q is necessarily a geodesic in the same fiber?(we do not assume any completeness). BTW may you ellaborate your answer?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  In response to your question about the more general case of a Riemannian submersion (and where I assume that you meant $p=v$ and $q=w$), the answer is a definite 'no', even in the case that the source and target of the Riemannian submersion are complete. Just take the standard flat metric on $M = \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}$ where the action is $n\cdot(x,y) = (\,x+2\pi\,n,\, (-1)^ny\,)$ and the submersion is $\sigma([x,y]) = \mathrm{e}^{ix}$ and look at the shortest path from $[0,a]$ to $[0,-a] = [2\pi, a]$ for $a>\pi$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Thank you very much  for your attention to my question and your comment. I realize from your comment  that the total space of the Mobius  bundle is a  counter example that is a  geodesic joining two cofiber points  are not necessarilly vertical.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Very interesting example!

Comment: @RobertBryant  Is there a counter example  with extra condition of  orientability?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  Yes, there is an orientable counterexample.  Just let $M=\mathbb{R}^3/\mathbb{Z}$ with action $n\cdot(x,y,z) = (x{+}2\pi\,,\,(-1)^ny\,,\,(-1)^nz\,)$ and let the submersion $\sigma:M\to S^1$ be $\sigma([x,y,z])=\mathrm{e}^{ix}$.  The same construction works with $p=[0,a,0]$ and $q = [0,-a,0]=[2\pi,a,0]$, but now $M$ is orientable.

Comment: @RobertBryant Thank you. In fact you consider the direct sum of the Mobius  bundle with itself.  BTW  what can be said  about the  main question of this post?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  As for the main question, Petrunin's argument is correct.

Comment: @RobertBryant so we can construct  compact Riemanian manifold $M,N$ with Riemannian submersion such that  the minimizing curve joining two cofiber points is not necessarily a vertical curve:We choose a  huge $2$-torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ and the same action you mentioned on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{T}^2 $, instead of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  BTW For what kind of principal bundles this pathology would not occure? that is for what kind kind of principal bundles the geodesics joining two points on the same fibers must be vertical curves?

Comment: @GabeK  your comments leads me to the following question:"Are there some other kind of Sasaki metric'?

Comment: You can use an arbitrary affine connection (independent of the metric)  to define the splitting and this is still called a 'Sasaki metric.' A good reference on the topic is the following paper by Satoh: https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10824

Comment: By choosing a pair of connection and metric,  you can use this construction to find complex/ almost-complex manifolds with very interesting geometry. It's also worth noting that the answer to your original question is negative if you use this more general construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Let me expand my comment to remove the question from unanswered.*

Any point in $w\in\mathrm{T}M$ is a pair $w=(V,p)$ where $p\in M$ and $V\in\mathrm{T}_pM$.

Let $t\mapsto w(t)=(V(t),\gamma(t))$ be a curve in $\mathrm{T}M$.
Let $V=V(0)$ and $p=\gamma(0)$.
Note that
$$w'(0)=\nabla_{\gamma'(0)}V\oplus \gamma'(0)\in \mathrm{T}_{p}M\oplus\mathrm{T}_{p}M=\mathrm{T}_{(V,p)}\mathrm{T}M.$$

Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle V\oplus 0,w'(0)\rangle
&=\langle V,\nabla_{\gamma'(0)}V\rangle=
\\
&=\tfrac12\cdot\langle V,V\rangle'(0).
\end{aligned}
$$
It follows that $(V,p)\mapsto V\oplus 0$ is the gradient of the function $f\colon(V,p)\mapsto \tfrac12\cdot\langle V,V\rangle$.
Whence the statement follows.

Comment: Thank you very much Anton  for your very interestinganswer. Sorry my late attention